# Invalid access token (Linkedin )

Tags: linkedin-api

So I'm triying to get list of companies by keyworkd using linkedin API

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search:(companies:(id,name,description,website-url))?keywords=dentist&oauth2_access_token=access_token&format=json
```

but I got this error : Invalid access token.
Am I missing something ?

Comment: are you sure your access token is still valid?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I check this ?

Comment: when you receive your [LinkedIn token](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#) there is the *expires_in* property, If your token is expired, you will have to refresh it. So with OAuth you have to rememeber access_token, expiry time and the refresh token. Based on the response you've provided your token is expired, revoked or you used some other (wrong) value instead of the access token

Comment: @gusto2 - Hi, how can we get access token from javascript api.  I cant get a proper documentation.  Can you please guide me.

Comment: @Sankar just search for it. You can have an [application token](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow) (all calls are on behalf of an application) or [user token](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) (all calls are on behalf of a user). Just follow the guides

Comment: @gusto2 thanks man, but i'm getting {"error":"access_denied","error_description":"This application is not allowed to create application tokens"}

Comment: @Sankar Your application will not have the ability to use LinkedIn's client credentials flow from the start. You have to contact them and explain why you cannot use user context. So - you rather use default (3-legged) OAuth with user access token

Comment: @gusto2 can you please explain what is 3-legged OAuth ?

Comment: @gusto2 also i tried to do 
$.ajax({
   url:'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken/grant_type=authorization_code&code=AQSTdbolwaw7bU7xoy9xHWaeeXH707RASVl4XiIUGdnkV4ho0Aerdxi0R58xecO-bmQl3TA19_uIbJ_hL9HUVP3FLoEpeZg8iDfNdhA8xr5XTcZ81la176kmIZNfiLCFx5k_xxdSxVSd60YVcBV8-j9WhZtO1w&redirect_uri=http://localhost/workout/linkedin.html&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx',
   type : 'POST',   
   headers:{ContentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
   success : function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
   }
  });
but not able to get

Comment: @Sankar just seach for it, you have plenty of guides - [example](https://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/using-linkedin-javascript-api-for-user-authentication-and-profile-retrieval.html)